# File filter not working in Spark StreamingContext.fileStream(...) API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm building a Spark Streaming application where my requirement is to read all pre-existing files in a directory being monitored.

I'm using `StreamingContext.fileStream(...)` API for this. This API needs one to pass the filter function. In my case I'm always returning `true` from this as I need to read all the files.
Also the `newFilesOnly` flag in `StreamingContext.fileStream(...)` is set to `false`.

[Here's API [doc]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html#fileStream(java.lang.String,%20scala.Function1,%20boolean,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag))

But, no matter what filter function returns or `newFilesOnly` flag is set to, the RDDs created in corresponding DStream are empty.

**Here's the code snippet:**

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(30))
val filterF = new Function[Path, Boolean] {
    def apply(x: Path): Boolean = {
      println("In File " + x.toString) //Prints exisitng file's path as expected
      true
    }
}
val strm = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("s3n://<bucket>/", filterF, false).map(_._2.toString)
strm.print()     //DOESN'T PRINT ANYTHING
```

I have tried different combinations of return values from filter function and newFilesOnly flag, nothing worked.

If I use `StreamingContext.textFileStream(...)` instead, it works fine, but reads only new files which is expected behavior from this API.

Am I missing something here? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you triggering this action, i.e. do you copy new files in that bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by increasing the ignore window of the `FileInputDStream`. This can be done by changing `spark.streaming.fileStream.minRememberDuration` property.
The default value is 1 min, all the files I tested with had modification time older than 1 min, so they got ignored.
See the code documentation [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/FileInputDStream.scala#L34) for more details.